# does a Grails' domain read() function use the second level cache?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I know that the `get()` method uses the second level cache, but I cannot find any documentation about whether the `read()` method uses the cache.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`read()` does not use the second-level cache.

You can test this by creating a sample app with SQL logging enabled and calling both `get()` and `read()` on a domain with `cache true` in its `mapping` block. `get()` will hit the cache and not generate any SQL but `read()` will execute a query.

In [the code for `read()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html#d0e3068) you can see that it uses a criteria to fetch a read-only instance of a domain. Hibernate only uses the second-level cache for `load()`, `get()`, and [several other methods](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html#d0e3071) but not criteria.